# PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL return different values on different machines

Tags: php, filter-var

I tested form validators for email field and inputted long email:

```
 $email = 'dfgjfdjglkdfjglkjdfgldfjglkdfjgkldfjlkgjdlkfjglkdfjkgdklfjgldkfjgldlfjgkldfjglkdfjglkdfklgjlkdfjkgkdfjlkgfjldkgkldjfgkljdfkgjlkdfgljdlf@mail.com';
```

On the local machine function filter_var return string with email:

```
 $email = 'dfgjfdjglkdfjglkjdfgldfjglkdfjgkldfjlkgjdlkfjglkdfjkgdklfjgldkfjgldlfjgkldfjglkdfjglkdfklgjlkdfjkgkdfjlkgfjldkgkldjfgkljdfkgjlkdfgljdlf@mail.com';

 die(var_dump(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)));
```

But on the remote server this code returns FALSE.

PHP version on local machine - 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.22

On the remote machine  - 5.3.28

Has filter_var function been changed between this version of PHP? Why I receive different values with the same code?

Comment: Confirmed: http://3v4l.org/6gMAb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` has been updated a couple of times since 5.3.2 (you really should update your version BTW). The most notable update was [this bug-fix](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52929) causing a seg-fault when the input/address-to-validate was too long.
Along side this fix (which is logged twice), [Rasmus Lerdof](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49576) on `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` returning false positives. Though, AFAIKT, this is not likely to be the cause of your woes.
A couple of other changes include bugs involving special chars like `?`, `>1` and `=`.
Anyway, to see all the changes since PHP5.3.2, just check [the changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) on their website...

Again: update your local version, it's getting rather dated. Given that you're running ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-dev
//optionally
$ sudo apt-get install php5-dev --install-suggests
```

If you're running mint:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-dev --install-recommends --install suggests
```

on both distro's, preferably run `sudo apt-get update` first, of course...

Answer (score 0):

On the [PHP's changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) you can see at least two issues (search for FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) between the versions you mentioned. That could be a starting point to do more searches.

Then what about updating your local PHP version? The one you're using is pretty old...